# Kotlin Ktor: GCP App Engine Application: Won't connect to GCP Postgres. Connection Timeout

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, google-app-engine, ktor, kotlin-exposed

I have written a simple Google Cloud App Engine application using Kotlin's Ktor framework.

The app worked perfectly deployed on App Engine before I tried adding the Database. After adding a GCP Postgres Database to the project that connects using the Exposed Library it now fails. **It works locally** on my home machine, but when I deploy to Google Cloud, It gives the following errors...

**When I Browse to the Web Site:**

upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination

---

**Logged in GCP Console:**

Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
at ..

**And...**
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.

I have isolated the problem to the following method.
`

```
fun initDatabase(){

    val jdbcUrl = ConfigManager.getStringProperty("postgres_db.jdbcUrl")
    val usr = ConfigManager.getStringProperty("postgres_db.username")
    val pw = ConfigManager.getStringProperty("postgres_db.password")
    val driver = ConfigManager.getStringProperty("postgres_db.driverClassName")
    db = Database.connect(jdbcUrl, driver, usr, pw)
    transaction(db) {
        SchemaUtils.createMissingTablesAndColumns(UserTable)

        UserTable.insert {
            it[email] = "wwwdddggg@gmail.com"
            it[passworld] = "Hello!"
        }
    }
}
```

`

I don't understand why it works locally but not on google cloud app engine. I had to add my local IP address to the list of connections in the GCP SQL settings menu for it to work on my machine. Do I have to add my apps ip address too?

Comment: When you say it works locally, did you run your App with ```dev_appsever.py```? Using that is the way to simulate production (it's not exactly a one to one match but it's the closest you'll get). Just running your App with the idiomatic way of running Apps in your programming language doesn't necessarily mean it'll work when deployed to GAE

Comment: @NoCommandLine It was working fine when deployed before. I did try that py script and it did something, Idk how to test if it works now